# Is my drive encrypted? I can read encrypted partition without providing password

Tags: partitioning, password, encryption, ecryptfs

Please help me determine if my is drive encrypted or not, what did I do wrong? I used Ubuntu Disk Utility for creating encrypted partition and I choose encrypted partition and provided a password, after this I expected the partition dump to be encrypted.

Inserted 256 MB SD card with encrypted Ext4 partition with a non-empty pass-phrase. After being asked for password, I escaped the dialogue and did not provide it, volume was visible to Ubuntu Disk Utility but appeared locked as in screenshot.

I copied the device content to a file and opened it with Nano text editor using dd command, to my surprise I could read my password files and content of a text file.

*$ sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/home/test.dat*

Then I opened test.dat with *$ sudo nano test.dat* and it was readable.

[image]

Output of *$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mmcblk0p1:*

```
LUKS header information for /dev/mmcblk0p1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    cbc-essiv:sha256
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      6a 18 ec dd 69 40 ae d7 0f 4d e3 97 78 e4 37 34 89 5f 96 62 
MK salt:        0c 11 ac 0b f6 a4 c7 8a 56 b2 08 5a 5f d5 f9 af 
                71 79 b2 b2 10 de 9c ad 69 cb 07 b0 1d 34 11 18 
MK iterations:  36000
UUID:           672050ee-f18b-4811-b4c9-19209a2db971

Key Slot 0: DISABLED
Key Slot 1: ENABLED
    Iterations:             145517
    Salt:                   9d f9 22 84 c7 22 14 94 f5 5a 29 62 84 f5 68 09 
                            f9 a8 88 28 35 92 cd eb 3b b2 e7 16 d2 a5 10 89 
    Key material offset:    264
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

In the summary, the lesson is to always fill your media with zeros before creating encrypted partition, it is not done automatically, I did not wipe my SD card and all this was the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's indeed quite disturbing.

May be you can double check from the command line with:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

It should spit out something like

```
LUKS header information for /dev/mmcblk0p1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      50 21 48 22 e3 5e 83 ff 09 eb 56 48 8a 57 44 cf 23 9c ae 9f 
MK salt:        0c c0 81 cb 14 17 08 b3 5b c5 91 b9 9e 38 a5 87 
                36 db 6f 16 55 d2 92 06 e3 96 0e 94 73 8e 13 27 
MK iterations:  32125
UUID:           0080a648-0f64-4ea9-abe2-18585a2da9b1

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             256000
    Salt:                   73 19 d4 9c a7 24 f3 bc 2c f8 77 8c 98 b9 46 0b 
                            00 51 d3 bd bb 07 d5 38 e2 12 ff 34 3b 3d 31 42 
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

It is the data of the LUKS header of the encrypted partition

p.s: By the way, which version of Disks utility are you using ? Mine is a little different.

May be you have saved the password of the encrypted partition ? But if Disks shows it locked, it is locked.
When it is locked, look in */dev/mapper* directory for link like *luks-0080a648-0f64-4ea9-abe2-18585a2da9b1*. If it is there, then you have an unlocked LUKS partition. Check output of *mount* to find out if it is the sd card

Comment: Nothing is in /dev/mapper, only a control file. My version of Disk Utility is 3.0.2, by the way system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 3.13.0-43-generic. My password is not saved, I use forget immediately option.

$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mmcblk0p1 outputs cipher name aes and cypher mode cbc-essiv:sha256, I will post it into the main question.

Comment: What could have happened is that the password file was previously on the same SD card unencrypted. When you formatted with encrypted partition, you did not use the option to overwrite all the disk with zero. So even though the disk is encrypted, and your password file has been encrypted to disk, what you can see is the old password file that was unencrypted.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I just created a new encrypted partition on newly formatted SD card and copied all files inside, this time it looks unreadable, all the keywords I could read before are not showing, i looks encrypted, so the lesson is format and zero your media before encrypting, otherwise this could happen.